# Differential Equation: $ 6t^3 \frac{dx}{dt} - 2x - 8 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the value of $k$ for which the constant function $x(t)=k$ is a solution of the differential equation $6t^3 \dfrac{dx}{dt} - 2x - 8 = 0.$

I have no idea where to begin! This doesn't seem to be separable or anything like that.

I'm sure this is an easy problem once its in the right form but I cannot seem to get it there.

Any help or tips is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: substitute $k$ for $x$ in $$6t^3 \dfrac{dx}{dt} - 2x - 8 = 0 \tag 1$$ and observe $\dfrac{dk}{dt} = 0.$

$\bf edit:$
let us just try $x = -4$ and see what happens.
$$6t^3 \dfrac{d (-4)}{dt} - 2(-4) - 8$$ which is equal to zero. therefore $x = -4$ is a solution of $(1).$

Comment: I don't see it. How does substition help? k is just as unknown as x itself.

Comment: Also how do you know dk/dt = 0? I am truly not seeing it.

Comment: @user111532. What is the derivative of a constant number?

Comment: AH ok!! I was thinking of it as a variable not a constant! Sorry my bad! Make sense now! Thank you very much! I owe you a coffee or something lol!

Comment: @user111532, how did you know that coffee is my favorite drink.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite you differential equation as
$$\frac{1}{2x+8}\frac{dx}{dt}=6t^3,$$
You see that it is actually separable. Then,
$$\int\frac{1}{2x+8}dx=\int6t^3dt.$$
Now solve for $x$ in terms of $t$. You should find that 
$$x(t)=Ce^{-\frac{1}{6t^2}}-4.$$
This will be a constant solution if and only if $C=0$, in which case $x(t)=-4$.